# How can I send an email using SendGrid C# library from a synchronous method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sendgrid

I need to send emails from a Asp.net WebForms application that is using synchronous methods. I know I can send emails using SMTP but I would like to send the emails using the SendGrid C# library API which is faster (from my testing). https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp

Here is my code. Which of the five methods below are correct? They all work and Visual Studio shows no errors. I don't want to cause an error in a production website from using the incorrect method.

```
static void SendSampleEmailSync()
{
    var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
    var from = new EmailAddress("123@sink.sendgrid.net", "example user");
    var subject = "Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun";
    var to = new EmailAddress("123@sink.sendgrid.net", "example user");
    var plainTextContent = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";
    var htmlContent = "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with C#</strong>";
    var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);

    // Method 1
    var task = Task.Run(() => client.SendEmailAsync(msg));
    var result = task.Result;

    // Method 2
    var result2 = client.SendEmailAsync(msg).Result;

    // Method 3
    _ = client.SendEmailAsync(msg);

    // Method 4
    client.SendEmailAsync(msg).ConfigureAwait(false);

    // Method 5
    var result4 = Task.Run(() => client.SendEmailAsync(msg)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From what I read on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development#the-thread-pool-hack

It looks like the best way would be to use this method:

```
var result = Task.Run(() => client.SendEmailAsync(msg)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: Calling **Task.Run()** is not necessary if **SendEmailAsync()** returns a Task. You can just call **GetAwaiter()** on that: `client.SendEmailAsync(msg).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`

Answer (score -2):

You can use like this.

```
static async Task Execute()
    {
        var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NAME_OF_THE_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_FOR_YOUR_SENDGRID_KEY");
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var from = new EmailAddress("email@xyz.com", "Sample User");
        var subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
        var to = new EmailAddress("email@xyz.com", "Sample User");
        var plainTextContent = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";
        var htmlContent = "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with C#</strong>";
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    }
```